# ¿Hacer que aparezcan los ceros en laravel?

Tags: php

Hola tengo un pequeño detalle en mi proyecto de laravel. en mi bade de datos tengo el id de los productos de tipo zerofill los cuales me aparecen bien en mi gestor de base de datos. Tambien tengo una tabla donde listo los productos con dos decimales los cuales representan los centavos. En mi base de datos aparece todo normal pero en las vistas de laravel no me aparecen lo cual me desordena un poco la lista de precios. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que en el caso de los productos me aparezcan los ceros de adelante y en el caso de los precios que me aparezcan los centavos y de ese modo tenerlos alineado. De antemano gracias. En mi vista tengo un foreach normal:

```html
 <table class="table table-productos table-responsive-md" id="tabla-productos">
        
        <a href="{{ action('ProductController@create')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-crea mb-2 p-2">Crear producto</a>
        <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control col-md-4 my-2" placeholder="Buscar producto">
        <thead class="thead-dark p-2">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th class="text-left">Categoria</th>
                <th class="text-right">Stock</th>
                <th class="text-right">Precio</th>
                <th class="text-right">Impuesto</th>
                <th class="text-right">Precio Total</th>
                <th class="text-center">Acción</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr class="fila">
                <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                <td class="text-left">{{$product->categories->name}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{$product->stock}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">${{$product->price}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{$product->tax}}%</td>
                <td class="text-right">${{$product->priceTotal}}</td>
                <td class="text-center"> 
                <a href="{{action('ProductController@edit',['id'=>$product->id])}}" class="btn btn-editar"><i class="fas fa-edit text-info"></i></a>
                <a href="{{action('ProductController@delete',['id'=>$product->id])}}" class="btn btn-eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: BetaM si claro. Donde te puedo aumentar la reputación. Tu casi siempre respondes mis preguntas de laravel

Comment: No hay necesidad de eso @Jesu sobre todo por que la solución no es mia, así que en todo caso quien merece el upvote es quien respondió en ese enlace pero no yo

Answer (score 2):

Usar la función `number_format()` debería funcionar, por ejemplo:

```
<td class="text-right">${{ number_format($product->price, 2) }}</td>
```

[Documentación de la función PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).